# WCF "Basic" transport security issue when hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-security

I am attempting to secure a new .Net 4.5 WCF service using HTTPS / SSL, Basic client credentials and the [WebHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding.aspx). From reading up online I found a good series of [Blog Posts from Allen Conway](http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/using-basic-authentication-in-rest.html) which I have used as a template.

**WCF configuration**

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webInteropSecureBinding" allowCookies="false" maxBufferPoolSize="2097152" maxBufferSize="2097152" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="PsmDataProvider.PsmProvider" behaviorConfiguration="SecureRest">
        <clear />
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webInteropSecureBinding" name="PsmProvider" contract="PsmDataProvider.IPsmProvider" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" listenUriMode="Explicit" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:44300/PsmProvider/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SecureRest">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" 
                                    customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="PsmDataProvider.Security.CustomerUserNamePasswordValidator, PsmDataProvider"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**CustomerUserNamePasswordValidator**

I have stubbed out the CustomerUserNamePasswordValidator implementation and have confirmed that the constructor is called before the exception is raised.

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Selectors;

namespace PsmDataProvider.Security
{
    internal class CustomerUserNamePasswordValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator, ICustomerUserNamePasswordValidator 
    {

        public CustomerUserNamePasswordValidator()
        {
        }

        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {          
            if (userName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("userName","The username must be provided in the request to access this service");
            if (password == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("password", "The password must be provided in the request to access this service");

        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the code in VS2012 through IIS Express the service fails to start with the below error.

[image]

If I remove the [clientCredentialType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.httptransportsecurity.clientcredentialtype.aspx) from the configuration then it works but I require the additional security of using the username / password validation on the service and possibly at a method level in the future.

Is this something I have configured incorrectly in the WCF config or a problem with the configuration in IISExpress?

Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be when using Basic Authentication when hosting the service in IIS as IIS wants to handle the authentication.

This is discussed in [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phenning/archive/2008/01/11/custom-usernamepassword-validators-in-net-framework-3-5.aspx)

> In the version of WCF that shipped with .Net Framework 3.0 we didn't
>   support custom validators with transport level HTTP security. We
>   received much feedback from the community that this was a highly
>   desired feature, so I'm happy to say we added support for this
>   scenario in the 3.5 release of the .Net Framework. Note that this is
>   only supported under self hosted services.

There is a resolution as discussed in [Allen Conway's Blog Post](http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/using-basic-authentication-in-rest.html) by implementing a custom authorisation manager derived from [ServiceAuthorizationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceauthorizationmanager.aspx)

**CustomAuthorizationManager**

```
public class CustomAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager 
{
    private const string UserName = "username";
    private const string Password = "password";

    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        string authHeader = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Authorization"];

        if ((authHeader != null) && (authHeader != string.Empty))
        {
            string[] svcCredentials = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII
                                        .GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Substring(6)))
                                        .Split(':');

            var user = new { Name = svcCredentials[0], Password = svcCredentials[1] };

            if ((user.Name.Equals(UserName) && user.Password.Equals(Password)))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"PsmProvider\"");
            throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }

}
```

**Config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webInteropSecureBinding" allowCookies="false" maxBufferPoolSize="51200" maxBufferSize="51200" maxReceivedMessageSize="51200">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="PsmDataProvider.PsmProvider" behaviorConfiguration="SecureRest">
        <clear />
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webInteropSecureBinding" 
                    name="PsmProvider" contract="PsmDataProvider.IPsmProvider" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:44300/PsmProvider/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SecureRest">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="PsmDataProvider.Security.CustomAuthorizationManager, PsmDataProvider"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Note**

Also note a comment from Travich regarding the IIS / IIS Express configuration

> Travich said... One thing to help other users. It was briefly stated,
>   but something I overlooked... Turn off Basic Auth in IIS and remove
>   tag from your webHttpBinding!

Works for me.